# Cross-Account Lambdas to API Gateway Setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

So the scenario is we have 3 different accounts(EDGE, PROD, DEV). I want to create some APIs in EDGE account and integrate them with lambdas in DEV and PROD Account respectively. 
I have 2 different stages of API : dev/prod and also have defined integration of API : LAMBDA with target = ${stageVariables.LAMBDA}.
When I mention the full ARN of LAMBDA in stage variables it shows the following error after api hit:

```
{
"message": "1 validation error detected: Value \'arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:XXEDGEACCOUNTXX:function:arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:XXDEVACCOUNTXX:function:funcName\' at \'functionName\' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: (arn:(aws[a-zA-Z-]*)?:lambda:)?([a-z]{2}((-gov)|(-iso(b?)))?-[a-z]+-\\d{1}:)?(\\d{12}:)?(function:)?([a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]+)(:(\\$LATEST|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+))?"
}
```

with

```
target = arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:${stageVariables.ACC}:function:${stageVariables.LAMBDA}/invocations
```

I get error of invalid function ARN or URI while saving it..

Please help.
PS. Permissions policy are attached perfectly fine. Issue is API gateway check Lambda in own account only that's why read only function name and keep account number fixed.

Comment: This `funcName\' at \'functionName\'` is incorrect function name.

Comment: Basically it is building, "func arn with edge account + func arn with dev account". actually my basic requirement is ..: I want to keep account number also as a stage variable.. (want to call two different lambdas of different account for two different stages

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the below statement

```
target = arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:${stageVariables.ACC}:function:${stageVariables.LAMBDA}/invocations
```

**${stageVariables.LAMBDA}** in the above statement is getting resolved to the lambda function arn. Hence there is a validation error.

```
arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:XXEDGEACCOUNTXX:function:arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:XXDEVACCOUNTXX:function:funcName
```

Also, noticed that the target arn your building is incorrect and should be of the below form

A stage variable can be used in place of a Lambda function name, or version/alias, as shown in the following examples.

```
arn:aws:apigateway:<region>:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account_id>:function:${stageVariables.<function_variable_name>}/invocations

arn:aws:apigateway:<region>:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account_id>:function:<function_name>:${stageVariables.<version_variable_name>}/invocations
```

For more information can go through this link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/aws-api-gateway-stage-variables-reference.html

Comment: Exactly I don't want ${stageVariables.LAMBDA} to be resolved as full ARN... I have been gone thru that link, actually my basic requirement is ..:  I want to keep account number also as a stage variable.. (want to call two different lambdas of different account for two different stages). I correct myself, target I am using is the following arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:${stageVariables.ACC}:function:${stageVariables.LAMBDA}

Comment: Currently, they dont support Account ID to be passed as a stage variable, its an API Gateway limitation. You can check the below link for more details. https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/87